# wkhtmltopdf multiple pages avoid page break

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am generating a pdf file from two urls, which is working fine so far. The only problem is, I do not want a page break between those two files. The second file should start directly after the first has ended. As both are html files on my server, I tried to just not close the body and html tag in the first file, but had no luck with that.

My executed script looks like this:

```
'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf ' . $sessionstring . '--no-stop-slow-scripts --print-media-type --enable-javascript --margin-top 35mm --margin-bottom 25mm --margin-right 25mm --margin-left 20mm --orientation portrait --header-html "' . $env['HEADER'] . '"  --header-spacing 10 -s A4 --dpi 96 --encoding utf-8 --image-quality 100 ' . $env['CONTENT'] . ' ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $outputname
```

Any hints to achieve that? Btw, I can't just combine both files before sending to WKHTML. I really do need to combine them within WKHTML.

Answer (score 0):

WK will always create a page break after each separate input, so there's no way to do it that way.

I would really just run with finding a way to combine the two files.

For example, this can easily be achieved using a PHP script:

```
$file1 = file_get_contents('path_to_file1');
$file2 = file_get_contents('path_to_file2');
file_put_contents('save_path', $file1 . $file2);
```

You could even then just run the WK script via the same PHP script:

```
exec('wkhtmltopdf your_wk_params_here');
```